# Update or create nested records using trpc/prisma

Tags: prisma, trpc, t3

I have an prisma(postgresql)/trpc/next.js that uses referenced tables. So for example I have models that look like:

```
model Class {
   id String @id
   name String
   lectures Lectures[]
}

model Lectures {
  id String @id
  text String
  classId String
  class Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
}
```

I've been trying to simply my next.js code, by just calling a "general" update on Class whenever any Class attribute is changed.

So something like:

```
  const classUpdate = trpc.class.update.useMutation();
  ...
  classUpdate.mutate(...myClass, name: newName);
```

I think i'd like to do something similar, where whenever there is a change to a Lecture for the Class (create/update/delete), i can simply call my "top-level" `classUpdate.mutate(..)` and pass in the new complete JSON tree structure that represents the Class, Lectures (and any other references/nested references that i might add later).

So something like:

```
  const classUpdate = trpc.class.update.useMutation();
  ...
  classUpdate.mutate(...myClass, lectures: [ ...myClass.lectures, newLecture ]);
  ... 
  classUpdate.mutate(...myClass, lectures: [ ...myClass.lectures, changedExistingLecture ]);
```

Im unclear if I can do this - and if so, what would the trpc procedure definitions look like... Or if i should be doing this at all; Should I be making specific trpc routers for each model (so a `lectureCreate.mutate(..)`, lectureUpdate.mutate(..)`and`lectureDelete.mutate(..)`)

I might be approach this from a GQL mindset where I think of my models as 1 big JSON tree of fields and sub-objects (tables in my case), and want to just mutate that complete abstraction in one go, versus breaking each action up by model/relationship.